# String.Format For SQL Connection String

Tags: sql, vb.net

I need to convert a SQL connection string into a `String.Format` line

The line that I need to convert is this:

```
WHERE full_name = @FullGraveNumber AND cemetery_id = @CemeteryID
```

Both the`full_name` and `cemetery_id` are variables, but I have not idea how to construct the 
`String.Format` line.

Comment: I'm confused, you're talking about connection strings but the line you're converting is part of a query? I have to admit I'm loathed to touch this one because I think you're underestimating the problem, you've not given us a complete list of values of the clauses... have you considered you'll need to select which parameters go with the column names?

Comment: When using parameterized queries, you should use a built in function like [`SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), not `String.Format`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are looking for

```
Dim selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE full_name = @FullGraveNumber AND cemetery_id = @CemeteryID"
Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(selectCommand, yourconnetion)

cmd.Parameters("@FullGraveNumber").Value = value1
cmd.Parameters("@CemeteryID").Value = value2
```

or

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullGraveNumber", value)
```

Comment: This is what I thought originally however the OP seemed to imply that the columns/parameters could change... dynamic SQL style

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `ConnectionString` is already a `String` with no parameters, it does not need to converted using `String.Format`. Usually stored in `app.config`, you feed it [directly into SqlConnection object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7469at0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) upon creation.

Part of the query that you have is also a `String`, but this time it may be substituted with parameters. However, please don't do so and use SQL parameters instead (see @huMpty's answer).

`full_name` and `cemetery_id` are [SQL **parameters**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements), [variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke6sh835.aspx) is something else.

My suggestion it to learn the terminology first, before you do any coding. No offense, it would benefit you a lot, because you would be able to ask a proper question. Proper question means a fast and qualified answer. Improper questions are usually closed. These are the rules of StackOverflow.